# CentOS5でのNAPT設定方法の種類と、転送先の調査方法

Tags: network, iptables

たとえば、1つのサーバー(123.45.67.89)で、Tomcatインスタンスが大量に動いていたとします。

DNSサーバーは社内にあります。
各アプリケーションごとにサブドメインを分けており、
A.com
B.com
C.com
...
Z.com
とあったとします。

ssh接続権限があり、S.com:80/solrでSolrに接続できるとき、
S.comで、123.45.67.89の何番ポートにリクエストが飛んでいるかを調査する方法はありますか？

また、リクエストが処理されるまでの過程を細かく出力するコマンドがあった気がするのですがご存じの方はいらっしゃいますか？
(以前、DNS設定の間違い探しをするために使用した記憶が)

OSはCentOS5系
iptablesは使用されているかわからない(rootに入れば使えるかもしれないがroot権限はない)

※各ミドルウェアの予約ポート(8080等)は使用していません。
※ajp等、プロキシは使用していません。

Answer (score 2):

> S.com:80/solrでSolrに接続できるとき、
>   S.comで、123.45.67.89の何番ポートにリクエストが飛んでいるかを調査する方法はありますか？

`S.com:80/solr` に接続しているなら 123.45.67.89の80番ポートだと思います。

Comment: netstatで使用ポートを確認しましたが、80番ポートは使用されていませんでした。接続サーバーが間違っているということはありません。IPマスカレードで別ポートに転送しているということはないのでしょうか？

Comment: ご質問の情況がよくわからないので回答しづらいですね。通信経路上にNAPTする可能性のある通信機器（ルータやFirewall）は存在するかわかりますか？あと、Tomcatの設定ファイル server.xml を調べればリッスンポートが書いてあると思いますが 調べられますか？`netstat -anp` で Tomcatのプロセスのリッスンポートを確認できるなら質問に追記してもらえると何か分かるかもしれません。